# Lock with 3 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I don't understand my mistake, i will describe it and then i will post my code.
From main() i want to run 3 threads (each thread containing a loop for 3 women).
I have a method that prints each woman that enters the bathroom and each woman that out.I want to use lock so every 3 women in each thread would be written before the next thread will take place.the out put should be something like this:
woman 0 enters the bathroom
woman 0 exits the bathroom
woman 1 enters the bathroom
woman 1 exits the bathroom
woman 2 enters the bathroom
woman 2 exits the bathroom
and then 2 times for each thread.
my problem is that only one thread is writing and 2 that didnt reach the lock still waiting after i release the lock.
here is my code:(BathRoom class)

```
private Lock lockW=new ReentrantLock();
public int women_present;


public BathRoom(){
    women_present=0;//empty at start
}



public  void woman_wants_to_enter (int i) {
     lockW.lock();

     women_present++;
     System.out.println ("Woman " + i + " enters bathroom ");     }
public  void woman_leaves (int i) {
   try {
        Thread.sleep (1000);

     }catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
   System.out.println ("Woman " + i + " exits bathroom ");
   if((women_present%3)==0){
       women_present=0;
       lockW.unlock();
   } }
```

This is the Women class:

```
private int i; /* This identifies the woman. */
   private BathRoom bathroom;

public Woman (BathRoom bathroom,int i) { 
      this.i = i;
      this.bathroom = bathroom;
   }

public void run () {
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    try {
            Thread.sleep ((long) (500 * Math.random()));
         }catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         bathroom.woman_wants_to_enter (i);
         bathroom.woman_leaves (i);
      }
   }}
```

Comment: There is no sense in the `if((women_present%3)==0){` test. You are only unlocking if the number *is* already zero, letting the nonsensical `%3` aside… In the end, you don’t need the `women_present` counter at all. You are calling `lock()` for every `woman_wants_to_enter`, therefore, you have to call `unlock` for every `woman_leaves` as well. And then, you’re already done.

Comment: As i said each thread contains 3 women .

Comment: The question i have given is to unlock after each thread is finished not each woman in thread.you can think of it like each thread is a group of 3 women.

Comment: So what? As said, you are calling `lock` for each women, therefore, you have to call `unlock` for each women. The lock already maintains a counter to remember how often you have locked and unlocked. That’s why its implementation name is **Reentrant**Lock

Comment: Yes but if i will unlock the thread in woman_leaves(int i) the program will work but other women from other threads will enter no? I mean woman 0 from thread 1 and the woman 0 from thread 2,we told to print them as a cluster using locks and conditions

Comment: I don’t know how often it needs to be said that you must call `unlock` as often as you have called `lock` before. Otherwise, the lock is not free.

Comment: Sometimes, it helps to read the documentation. [`lock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#lock--): *If the current thread already holds the lock then the hold count is incremented by one and the method returns immediately*. [`unlock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#unlock--): *If the current thread is the holder of this lock then the hold count is decremented. If the hold count is now zero then the lock is released.*

Comment: Holger thanks for helping me out,please tell me something:from the run() method in women class each call for woman_wants_to_enter(i) acuire to lock?or the lock can be acuire once per thread?because as you see in each thread there is 3 calls for a method that check for locks.

Comment: I ask this becuase if i release the lock after every woman in threas i get wrong output becuase other threads accuire the lock before my thread prints all the cluster.i get output like:woman 0 enter woman 0 exit(calles from thread 1) then woman 0 enter woman 0 exit(from thread 2 or 3) instead the correct one should be:woman 0 woman 1 woman 2...from thread 1 and then release the lock for other threads to print their cluster.i hope that you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i took the liberty to modify your code :

```
  package stackoverflow;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class BathRoom {
    private Lock lockW=new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition c1=lockW.newCondition();
    public int women_present;


    public BathRoom(){
        women_present=0;//empty at start
    }



    public  void woman_wants_to_enter (int i) {
         lockW.lock();
         while(women_present!=i)
            try {
                c1.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


         System.out.println ("Woman " + i + " enters bathroom ");     }
    public  void woman_leaves (int i) {
       try {
            Thread.sleep (1000);

         }catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
       System.out.println ("Woman " + i + " exits bathroom ");
       women_present++;    
       if(women_present==3){
           women_present=0;
        }
       c1.signal();
       lockW.unlock();
 }
}
class Woman implements Runnable{
    private int i; /* This identifies the woman. */
       private BathRoom bathroom;

    public Woman (BathRoom bathroom,int i) { 
          this.i = i;
          this.bathroom = bathroom;
       }

    public void run () {
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try {
                Thread.sleep ((long) (500 * Math.random()));
             }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             bathroom.woman_wants_to_enter (i);
             bathroom.woman_leaves (i);
          }
       }
    }

public class testdummy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BathRoom b=new BathRoom();

        Woman w0=new Woman(b, 0);
        Woman w1=new Woman(b, 1);
        Woman w2=new Woman(b, 2);

        Thread A=new Thread(w0);
        Thread B=new Thread(w1);
        Thread C=new Thread(w2);

        A.start();
        B.start();
        C.start();



    }

}
```

I have made use of ***Condition object to synchronize the thread access to the method*** , its not perfect but it works , hope it will give you thoughts for a better approach.

Comment: lock.unlock() should be ideally inside a finally block

Comment: @demianr  can you upvote , if you feel this answer works for you

Answer (score 0):

First thread
In woman_wants_to_enter(), 
    thread aquires lock() so continues.
    woman_present is set to 1.

In woman_leaves(), woman_present is still 1 
    if (1 mod 3 is 1) so the unlock is not called

Second thread enters woman_wants_to_enter() but is waiting for the lock

Comment: In each thread there are 3 woman (loop in the run method) and only after that i want to release the lock the let other threads(with 3 woman in it)

Comment: I dont want to release every woman but every 3(numbers of women in each thread)